# PC turning on but no power to monitor or keyboard or mouse

Tags: boot, power, desktop-computer

I bought a Lenovo Legion 26AMR5 last January with these specs:

Ryzen 7 5800
RTX 3060 Ti
550W PSU
B550 Motherboard
16GB Ram

It was working fine for all that time, I was traveling a lot and so it was left there so I am not sure if it contains that much dust in it.

Today it shut down out of nowhere, I tried booting it up, suddenly the monitor, mouse, and keyboard do not recieve any signal, however, the pc itself seems to be working, CPU running, fans running, GPU running.

And so far those have never came back to life any time I tried today.

The monitor just says no signal, the mouse is not flashing, and the keyboard doesn't respond to anything, for example, the caps lock doesn't light up.

I feel like it could be the power supply, but I did not heavily use the pc that much.

Any guesses? Thank you so much!

Comment: Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the advice. I live in a village and there are no repair shops near me and I don't own a car. Is there a way I can do the fix myself provided that its a new PC?

Comment: `the pc itself seems to be working` .. probably not.  The fans getting power does not indicate that the machine posted.  Do you get any beeps when firing it up?  Also, unplug.  Hold down power +10 seconds.  Plug back in.  You need it to post.  Without the post, you can't even access the firmware.

Comment: No beeps at all. Just tried unplugging the power cable and holding down the button, still same issue :(

Comment: Quick test to see if it's HDD or OS failure, rather than (other) hardware, e.g., loose connector or power supply. Hold down the key to go to BIOS/UEFI, and then turn on the power with the power button. If the monitor still shows nothing, it's hardware failure.

Comment: I cannot do that because the keyboard itself does not work at boot.